# How to store byte[] image in mongodb for Doocr process

Tags: mongodb, rest, spring-mvc, ocr, tesseract

Hi how to store byte image in mongodb and perform doocr process(through public static void main). Is it possible through perform a doocr for stored image from mongodb

**Model:**

```
public class Photo {    
    @Id
    private String id;      
    private byte[] image; } getter & setter
```

**Controller**:

```
@Controller
public class PhotoController {
   @GetMapping("/photos/upload")
    public String uploadPhoto(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "hello");
        return "uploadPhoto";
    }
```

added mongodb image path after image stored on that. ?Is right way to do that

**MAIN:**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
{   
SpringApplication.run(StackoverflowApplication.class, args);            

   /// mongodb data path is it right ? for doocr
 File image = new File("mongodb://localhost:27017//test-db//user");

   // encode nd decode  sample

String encodedString =Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(originalInput. 
  getBytes());      
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedString);
    String decodedString = new String(decodedBytes);

    Tesseract tessInst = new Tesseract();
    tessInst.setDatapath("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\tessdata");
    try {
            String result= tessInst.doOCR(image);
            System.out.println(result);
    } catch (TesseractException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }           }
```

**is it possible or any other base64  needed for this.**

Comment: Did you look for GridFs in mongoDB. It is awsome if you want to store file in mongoDB

Comment: No actually am looking to perform a doocr [image to text ]process in my controller and store the image, text in mongodb. Is it possible with this image type because byte [] type only perform those tasks.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using spring. You can use `MultipartFile` to get the file in your controller and then use `Binary` of `org.bson` to store file to MongoDB , If your image size < 16MB (if image size > 16 MB you can use [GridFs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/mongodb/gridfs) ).

You need to add only one dependency to your project - `spring-data-mongoDB`

Let's take an example of a User collection which looks like this:

```
@Document
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    
    private String name;
    private Binary image;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Here you can see `Binary image` which represents your image file.

Now create a repository for this User collection using `MongoRepository`

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String>{

}
```

Create a Controller for demo purpose. Use `@RequestParam MultipartFile file` to get file to your controller, get bytes from file and set it to user object `user.setImage(new Binary(file.getBytes()));` complete example is below:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostMapping("/users")
    User createUser(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName(name);
        user.setImage(new Binary(file.getBytes()));
        
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @GetMapping("/users")
    String getImage(@RequestParam String id) {
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(id);
        Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
        
        return encoder.encodeToString(user.get().getImage().getData());

    }
}
```

Start the server and hit the end point as shown in below postman screenshot

[image]

Your data is stored in mongoDb in `BinData` format and to get the data from database please refer to `getImage` method of above code.

**EDIT:**

The question asker is using `tess4j` library for extracting text from image and `doOCR` is a method in this library. I have followed these steps to extract text from image in my spring boot application.

1. Install `tesseract-ocr` into your system:

   `sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr`
2. Download `eng.traineddata` training data from https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata and move it to project root folder.
3. Add below dependency to your project:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
   </dependency>
```

4. Add the below code to existing project:

```
@GetMapping("/image-text")
String getImageText(@RequestParam String id) {
    Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(id);
    ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(user.get().getImage().getData());
        BufferedImage bufferImg = ImageIO.read(bais);
        String imgText = instance.doOCR(bufferImg);
        return imgText;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "Error while reading image";
    }
}
```

Comment: followed step by step from the given data but while hit post method it's shown an error 404 not found . I didn't knew what happened. If it works based on the given image then how we perform on that ;                                                                            Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder(); then doocr() anything like that. ?.   Maybe created another @getmapping for that decode and doocr process because we store only encode details only.

Comment: 404 error is due to fact that the endpoint you are hitting is not present in your application

Comment: Here is my complete spring boot code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=10gDvS8dkbVGT_syyu5smhRt0vuAmgAU3

Comment: Oh ok i will check that.                                                                                      
 Does binary image data type really supports doocr process? Or change image type to byte[]. do you have idea about doocr[image to text] and store it mongodb or above the source that you gave enough for perform doocr.

Comment: I you check `getImage` method . `user.get().getImage().getData()` this line provide the image content in byte[]. Also I haven't worked on doocr

Comment: I have updated my answer . pls check it works for you this time

Comment: Hi  Image successfully stored & retrieved from mongodb  but, while hit @GetMapping("/image-text") in postman it's shown  500 error . I was installed tessract in local and add eng.traineddata  in  project root . Tried out with 
@RequestMapping(value = "/image-text",method = RequestMethod.GET) but not works.                                                                                                                            If a user want store that text how we do that. Maybe we add public string text  in user class and String imgText = instance.doOCR(bufferImg); then repo..save(text);

Comment: I was passed id correctly to retrive the image and worked perfectly but the same id for @RequestMapping(value = "/image-text") it's shown error bro. Is it possible to store in response text in mongodb. Shall user added with string text then save it in        String imgText = instance.doOCR(bufferImg); , repository.save(text);                    return imgText;                                                                                                                     Is that right i was guess?

Comment: "@RequestMapping(value = "/image-text") it's shown error bro" - I don't know . You need to debug this. It is better to save text version in DB Asynchronously(look for @Async annotation) because it will take more than 4-5 sec (Depending on your system) to process the image on http call

Comment: OK. Is it possible to perform mongodb stored image in local (public static void main) console part ?  instead of  "@RequestMapping                                                          
  public static void main(String ... args) 
    {                                                                                                                       
    File image = new File("mongodb://localhost:27017/springboot-mongo/photos ");     Tesseract tessInst = new Tesseract();
 tessInst.setDatapath("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop");
try {String result= tessInst.doOCR(image);

Comment: You can add this code in spring app itself. But annotate that method with @Async . look for https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the community project called [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) for Mongo for the content storage piece.  Spring Content is to unstructured data (documents, videos, images), what Spring Data is to structured data.  It provides an abstraction over Storage.  Giving you the same programming model in order to achieve REST-based content services quickly and easily.

You can add it to your project like this:

> pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-content-mongo</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.0</version>    <!-- 1.0.0.M1 for Spring Boot 2.2 -->
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-content-rest</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.0</version>    <!-- 1.0.0.M1 for Spring Boot 2.2 -->
</dependency>
```

Make sure you have a GridFsTemplate bean present in your application context.  Mongo storage and REST API are enabled.  Something like the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoStores
@Import(org.springframework.content.rest.config.RestConfiguration.class) // Enable REST API
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

   @Bean
   public GridFsTemplate gridFsTemplate() throws Exception {
      return new GridFsTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), mappingMongoConverter());
   }
   ...
```

To allow content to be associated with your Photo entity, give it the following attributes:

> Photo.java

```
public class Photo {    

    @Id
    private String id;      
    //private byte[] image;    replace this with -->

    @ContentId
    private String contentId;

    @ContentLength 
    private long contentLength = 0L;

    @MimeType
    private String mimeType;
```

Add a store interface:

> PhotoStore.java

```
public interface PhotoStore extends ContentStore<Photo, String> {
}
```

That's all that you need.  When your application starts Spring Content will see the dependencies on the Mongo/REST modules and it will inject a GridFS implementation of the `PhotoStore`, as well as an implementation of a Controller that supports full CRUD functionality and maps those operations onto the `PhotoStore` interface.  The REST endpoints will be available at `/photos`.

i.e.

`curl -X PUT /photos/{photoId} -F "file=@/some/image.jpg"` will create or update a photo

`curl -X GET /photos/{photoId}` will fetch the photo

`curl -X DELETE /photos/{photoId}` will delete the photo

There are a couple of getting started guides [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).  They use Spring Content for the filesystem but the modules are interchangeable.  The Mongo reference guide is [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/refs/release/mongo-index.html).  There is a tutorial video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbDaONWWT3s).  And an example project [here](https://github.com/paulcwarren/spring-content-examples/tree/master/spring-eg-content-mongo).

HTH